# beginner_question = 'When do we add arguments to functions?'

Tags: python, function, numpy, calling-convention

I was recently practicing some Python and I came onto a roadblock where I couldn't make my agg() to work, I later found out that it was because I didn't have to call the functions.

My question here is: I'd like somebody to please explain what are we exactly doing when we write () at the end of the function and what's the difference between doing it and not doing it

EDIT: THIS CODE IS EXAMPLE CODE, IM NOT LOOKING FOR AN ANSWER ON THIS CODE. I'M LOOKING FOR AN ANSWER ON THE CONCEPT OF CALLING OR NOT CALLING A FUNCTION AND HOW DOES THAT WORK.

What I was using which returned error: 'no a specified' (no argument)

```
sales_stats = sales.groupby('type')['weekly_sales'].agg([np.min(),np.max(),np.median(),np.mean()])
```

Correct code:

For each store type, aggregate weekly_sales: get min, max, mean, and median

```
sales_stats = sales.groupby('type')['weekly_sales'].agg([np.min,np.max,np.median,np.mean])
```

Comment: You missed some parentheses right after `'type'`. You want to be passing the *function* to the aggregate, not a value returned by it.

Comment: There are several uses for parenthesis. In you case `groupby('type')` it invokes the `groupby` function with `'type'` as parameter.

Comment: What would `'type'['weekly_sales']` be supposed to mean? What parameters does `sales.groupby` take? What does it output? If you don't really understand what calling a function means and what arguments are, I strongly recommend that you take a look at a good tutorial about basic Python, that will help you a lot - and SO is not meant to replace that...

Comment: I apologize for the parenthese issue, it wasnt the actual issue. I just want to know why we don't pass any arguments on the functions inside agg() and how does that work.

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: There *is* an argument to `agg`, it's `[np.min,np.max,np.median,np.mean]`. So, I don't really understand your question...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Thierry! but why do we not write agg(np.min()) instead of agg(np.min)? that's basically the question. I apologize if its not clear, im new to this forum!

Comment: Without parentheses, the function is not called, but represents the function itself (the object). With parentheses, the function is called, and represents the value that this call returns. In this case, functions are put into a list without executing them immediately. That list is passed to the `agg` method, which will take care of executing them.

Comment: Beware, neither numpy nor pandas are standard Python. If you want to learn Python, leave them away, because they are much more complex...

Comment: @trincot beautiful, that's all I wanted to know. Excellent explanation!!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!! I just want to grasp the concepts and not just copy paste!!

Apologies to everybody else for the way I worded my question!!! And thanks for the answers!! I'll try to write them better next time!! I will get better!

Comment: @julianlagier Functions in Python are first-class objects, which means they can be passed around like any other data type, like numbers or strings. So passing `func` into a function passes the function object in, where the caller is then free to call `func` when needed. But calling `func()` passes in the *return value* of `func`, instead of the function object.

Comment: Also I second @SergeBallesta's advice. Nothing wrong with learning numpy/pandas, but the syntax and concepts used can look very weird even to someone who has experience in Python, let alone a new programmer. I recommend you first spend a bit of time learning vanilla Python, and then go back to numpy/pandas.

Comment: @ChristianDean Another great explanation thanks! I'm doing pretty well on them atm, however i'm always open to new information, is there any particular source you recommend to learn the concepts?

Comment: @julianlagier Python itself? This page has a lot of good resources: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers. Also don't neglect YouTube either. If you're doing fine at the moment, then no need to feel like you have to stop learning what you're learning. I only recommend learning a bit more of vanilla Python because the question you asked here might be indictive that it might be quite hard to learn how to program, *and* learn how to program in numpy at the same time. But best of luck.

Comment: @ChristianDean Thank you!! Have a great day!! And I appreciate the answers!! One day I will be able to answer one for you as well!

Comment: The `groupby.agg` docs say it expects a function or list of functions.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html.  `[np.min,...]` is such a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
sales.groupby('type')['weekly_sales'].agg([np.min,...]
```

`sales` is a Pandas dataframe, `groupby('type')` is a method call that returns `GroupBy` object, which in turn has a `agg` method.

Looking up its docs:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html

According to that the first argument of `agg` is a

```
func : function, string, dictionary, or list of string/functions
```

In Python, functions are 'first class objects', that is, they can be passed as arguments just like numbers and lists, and can be put in a list as well.

`np.max` is a function (in the `numpy` module).  `[np.max, np.min]` is a list of functions.

`np.max` is the function:

```
In [2]: np.max
Out[2]: <function numpy.amax(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=<no value>, initial=<no value>, where=<no value>)>
```

`np.max(...)` is a calling of the function, and produces something else, not the function itself.  In this case it returns a number:

```
In [3]: np.max(np.array([1,2,3]))
Out[3]: 3
```

`agg` wants the function, not the number.  `agg` will take care of calling `np.max` with arrays (or lists or Series) from the group.

Note that just adding `()` to a function may not do anything useful.  It may even raise an error.

So you question is in part basic Python - the difference between a function and calling the function.  But also a `pandas` and `numpy` question.  And as such it requires reading the respective function/method documentation.

Note that the `agg` docs specifies what the `function` itself must accept.

Take the sample frame from the `agg` docs:

It shows providing `agg` with a string:

```
In [9]: df.groupby('A').agg('min')
Out[9]: 
   B         C
A             
1  1 -1.589447
2  3 -0.997238
```

`agg` recognizes a specific set of strings, which it converts into function calls.  Equivalently we can pass a function:

```
In [10]: df.groupby('A').agg(np.min)
Out[10]: 
   B         C
A             
1  1 -1.589447
2  3 -0.997238
```

But when we use `np.min()` as you do, we get an error:

```
In [11]: df.groupby('A').agg(np.min())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [11], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df.groupby('A').agg(np.min())

File <__array_function__ internals>:4, in amin(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: _amin_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

You summarized the error as " returned error: 'no a specified' (no argument)".  It is not a good idea to do that on SO.  You should read the error in full, and show it in full.  The traceback tells us that the problem is with the `np.min()` step.  It didn't get as far as calling `agg`.

- **read the traceback**
- **read the docs**

Comment: Beautiful answer, just gorgeous! God bless your soul!!!!! Next time I'll make sure to include that!!!

Absolutely stunning!!!! I paused my data analytics learning track to come back to functions as some other members recommended here and this makes a lot of sense!!!

Thanks again, this is awesome!!